ORA-12547 when trying to login to sqlplus
After database installation (Fedora Workstation 39) I am able to login to oracle database using oracle system user using following command:
sqlplus system/manager
I have another user called user that I added to groups oinstall,dba,oper. This user can execute lsnrctl status and tnsping without problems, but when trying to execute:
sqlplus system/manager I receive error ORA-12547: TNS:lost connection.
Surprisingly the same user can access database using command:
sqlplus system/manager@localhost/id.
Any idea how can I make user able to login using only sqlplus system/manager ?
Thanks in advance.

Hm, that doesn't make much sense. SQLPLUS requires username/password (and database) information. User named SCOTT connects as e.g. SQLPLUS scott/tiger. User named SYSTEM connects as e.g. SQLPLUS system/manager. User named USER (bad name, in my opinion) connects as SQLPLUS user/its_password. Why do you think that user USER should be able to connect as system/manager? User USER has to provide its username, not someone else's. Or did you just wrongly described situation you're in?

@Littlefoot For my development environment I need execute some scripts with oracle admin privileges, oracle database has its own admin users like sys or system. When logged in system terminal as oracle user I can successfully login to this oracle account using sqlplus system/manager command, and I need to have the same possibility on my actual working user.

Does this helps: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/os-authentication ?

This seems to be off-topic for this site. But have a look at Oracle Support doc 555565.1 (you need an account) for some ideas. Likely having nosuid on the mountpoint, from your description and a quick scan of that. (I wouldn't normally repeat even that much from MoS, but it's public on AskTom too.)
